# Jquery Using PrevAll to find previous span

Tags: jquery, html

Hello I am looking to get this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sLkvB/) working.

My objective is to make the `span` inside the `h2` that has been clicked also toggle text with the data.

I have a large amount of data formatted in the way below, but for this example I am only showing three `ul` sets.

Thank you.

(existing code below or in jsfiddle link above)

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".abc").click(function(){
        $(this).nextAll('ul:first').slideToggle(500, function() {
            $(this).prevAll('span:first').text($(this).is(':visible') ? "- Hide data" :     "- Show data");
        });
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<h2 class="abc">click1 <span>- Hide data</span></h2>
<p>text</p>
<ul>
    <li>data</li>
</ul>
<h2 class="abc">click2 <span>- Hide data</span></h2>
<p>text</p>
<ul>
    <li>data</li>
</ul>
<h2 class="abc">click3 <span>- Hide data</span></h2>
<p>text</p>
<ul>
    <li>data</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: By "text" you mean `<p>test</p>`?

Comment: @Biduleohm yes, sorry I have edited original post.

Comment: The `span` elements aren't siblings to the `ul` elements, the `h2` elements are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".abc").click(function(){
        var that = $(this);
        that.nextAll('ul:first').slideToggle(500, function() {
            that.find('span:first').text($(this).is(':visible') ? "- Hide data" : "- Show data");
        });
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sLkvB/3/)**